# RxJS combining pointerdown and pointermove events

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, svg, rxjs

I am implementing a drag and drop of SVG Image Elements on SVG Element. The idea is when the pointerdown event is fired, and the pointermove event is fired, the selected SVG Image Element is dragged to the pointer location, until the pointerup event is fired. I am using the RxJS fromEvent creational observable.

```
    import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { fromEvent, Observable, Subscription, Subject } from 'rxjs'
    import { RouterComponent, Router } from '../router/router.component';
    import { ToolbarComponent } from '../toolbar/toolbar.component';
    import { LinkComponent } from '../link/link.component';
    import * as d3 from 'd3';
    import { of } from 'rxjs';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-test',
      templateUrl: './test.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
    })
    export class TestComponent implements AfterViewInit {

      @ViewChild("svg") svgElement: ElementRef<SVGSVGElement>;

      svg: SVGSVGElement;

      moveObjectPointerDown: Subscription;
      moveObjectPointerMove: Subscription;
      moveObjectPointerUp: Subscription;

      linkPointerDown: Subscription;
      linkPointerMove: Subscription;
      linkPointerUp: Subscription;

      @ViewChild(ToolbarComponent) toolbarComponent: ToolbarComponent;
      @ViewChild(RouterComponent) routerComponent: RouterComponent;
      @ViewChild(LinkComponent) linkComponent: LinkComponent;

      constructor() {
      }

      ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.svg = this.svgElement.nativeElement;

        this.subscribeMoveMode();

        this.toolbarComponent.createRouter$.subscribe(() => {
          var router = this.routerComponent.create();
          this.routerComponent.add(router);
        });

        this.toolbarComponent.createHost$.subscribe(() => {
        });
      }

      unsubscribeMoveMode(): void {
        this.moveObjectPointerDown.unsubscribe();
        this.moveObjectPointerMove.unsubscribe();
        this.moveObjectPointerUp.unsubscribe();
      }

      unsubscribeLinkMode(): void {
        this.linkPointerDown.unsubscribe();
        this.linkPointerMove.unsubscribe();
        this.linkPointerUp.unsubscribe();
      }

      subscribeMoveMode(): void {

        var selectedElement: any;
        var offsetX: number;
        var offsetY: number;

        this.moveObjectPointerDown = fromEvent(this.svg, "pointerdown").subscribe((event: any) => {
          if (event.target.classList.contains("router")) {
            selectedElement = event.target;
            let targetPositionX = selectedElement.getAttributeNS(null, 'x');
            let targetPositionY = selectedElement.getAttributeNS(null, 'y');
            let mousePositionX = event.clientX;
            let mousePositionY = event.clientY;
            let ctm = this.svg.getScreenCTM();
            mousePositionX -= ctm!.e;
            mousePositionY -= ctm!.f;
            offsetX = mousePositionX - targetPositionX;
            offsetY = mousePositionY - targetPositionY;
          }
        });

        this.moveObjectPointerMove = fromEvent(this.svg, "pointermove").subscribe((event: any) => {
          if (selectedElement) {
            let mousePositionX = event.clientX;
            let mousePositionY = event.clientY;
            let ctm = this.svg.getScreenCTM();
            mousePositionX -= ctm!.e;
            mousePositionY -= ctm!.f;
            mousePositionX -= offsetX;
            mousePositionY -= offsetY;
            selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', mousePositionX);
            selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', mousePositionY);

            // update position of router
            this.routerComponent.update(selectedElement.id, mousePositionX, mousePositionY);
            
            //this.routerObserver.update(selectedElement.id, selectedElement.x.baseVal.value, selectedElement.y.baseVal.value);
            for (let linkID of this.routerComponent.getById(selectedElement.id)!.links) {
              this.linkComponent.update(linkID, mousePositionX + 25 - 1, mousePositionY + 25 - 1);
            }
          }
          event.preventDefault();
        });

        this.moveObjectPointerUp = fromEvent(this.svg, "pointerup").subscribe((event: any) => {
          selectedElement = null;
        });
      }

      subscribeLinkMode(): void {
        
        var selectedLineElement: any;
        var selectedRouterElement1: any;
        var selectedRouterElement2: any;
        
        this.linkPointerDown = fromEvent(this.svg, "pointerdown").subscribe((event: any) => {     
          selectedRouterElement1 = event.target;
          if (selectedRouterElement1.classList.contains("router")) {
            var router: Router | undefined = this.routerComponent.getById(selectedRouterElement1.id);
            if (router != undefined) {
              selectedLineElement = this.linkComponent.create(router.x + 25, router.y + 25, router.x + 25, router.y + 25);
            }
          }
        });

        this.linkPointerMove = fromEvent(this.svg, "pointermove").subscribe((event: any) => {

          if (selectedLineElement) {
            let ctm = this.svg.getScreenCTM();
            var mousePositionX = event.clientX;
            var mousePositionY = event.clientY;
            mousePositionX -= ctm!.e;
            mousePositionY -= ctm!.f;
            selectedLineElement = this.linkComponent.update(selectedLineElement.id, mousePositionX - 1, mousePositionY - 1);
          }
          event.preventDefault();
        });

        this.linkPointerUp = fromEvent(this.svg, "pointerup").subscribe((event: any) => {
          if (event.target.classList.contains("router")) {
            selectedRouterElement2 = event.target;
            var r1 = this.routerComponent.getById(selectedRouterElement1.id)!;
            var r2 = this.routerComponent.getById(selectedRouterElement2.id)!;
            if (r1.connectedTo.indexOf(r2) == -1 && r2.connectedTo.indexOf(r1) == -1) {
              var newLink = this.linkComponent.create(r1.x + 25, r1.y + 25, r2.x + 25, r2.y + 25);
              this.routerComponent.addLink(r1.id, newLink.id, r2);
              this.routerComponent.addLink(r2.id, newLink.id, r1);
            }
          }

          if (selectedLineElement) {
            this.linkComponent.remove(selectedLineElement.id);
            selectedRouterElement1 = null;
            selectedRouterElement2 = null;
            selectedLineElement = null;
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

My question is Is there a more clever way of doing this using RxJS combination operators? As opposed to having three independent observables with locally shared variables (selectedElement, offsetX, offsetY). Can I utilize combineLatest, or withLatestFrom, or others?

Comment: pointerdown$.pipe(switchmap((downEvent) =>pointerMove$.pipe(takeUntil(pointerup$)))).subscribe(evt => {/* evt is pointerMove event which will only be here between pointerdown and pointerup */ )). would that work for you?

Comment: @Andrei yes exactly this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do not reinvent the wheel. In other words, when trying to implement a new feature, look for an existing implementation. Also, make sure you trust the source code authors to avoid malware. This will save you a lot of time.

For this drag-and-drop feature, you could leverage the [Angular Material UI component library](https://material.angular.io/).

Follow these steps:

- Install required dependencies. For this, you can either install the [Component Dev Kit (CDK)](https://material.angular.io/cdk/categories) or the Angular Material library (which includes the CDK)

  - CDK only (simpler and faster): `npm i @angular/cdk`
  - Angular Material: `ng add @angular/material`
- Import the required module:

```js
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
// Other imports...

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, DragDropModule, ...],
  // ...
})
```

For standalone applications (the default since Angular v17), there are no `NgModule`s. So, you can use this instead:

```js
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
// Other imports...

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, DragDropModule, ...],
  // ...
})
```

- Final step: add the `cdkDrag` directive to an element (SVG `image` in this case):

```html
<svg width="200" height="150">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#e0e0e0" />
  <image href="favicon.ico" width="100" height="75" cdkDrag />
</svg>
```

There is a lot more that can be done with the `DragDropModule`.
Visit the [Drag and Drop](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) page for more information.